# .Net MVC DropDownList isn't rendered correctly when it's initially hidden

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I'm fairly new to this style of .Net MVC, so hopefully this something simple to fix.

I have an HTML table row that needs to be hidden when a page is loaded, then if an option from a drop down list (DDL) is selected, it is displayed. This hidden row includes another MVC DDL.

If I don't hide the row initially, the DDL renders correctly  However, if I use CSS/styles to hide the row, or use JQuery to hide the row after the page loads, the DDL renders as a completely empty list with nearly no standard actions.

```
<tr id="ifNotChosen">
    <td>Why not chosen?</td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.NotChosenReason, Model.NotChosenReasons,
            new { @class = "chosen-select-deselect", data_placeholder = "Select Not Chosen Reason", style = "width:200px;" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

At the end of the file is a script that includes all the actions, including the "hide" action. Since the script is at the end of the file, I would expect this to be run after the DOM elements are rendered, so it wouldn't affect how it looks. Evidently, this assumption is incorrect.

```
<script>
    ...

    $("#ifNotChosen").hide();

    ...
</script>
```

As I said, if the row isn't initially hidden, it renders correctly, with all the options available and the `data_placeholder` visible.  The below pic shows the DDL that determines if the 2nd DDL is visible or not. This shows the results of initially hiding the row, then making it visible after selecting the correct option in the first DDL. None of the options are able to be selected, since this also no longer acts like a normal DDL.

[image: Broken Drop Down List after being hidden]

FYI, all the research I've done so far only tells me how to hide or show a DDL, but doesn't address this weird issue.

So, my question is: how do I make this DDL list work correctly?

**Edit:**
This is a new field to a working form.  The JQuery gets included at the top of the page and the other JQuery on the page works just fine.

**Edit 2:**
After testing @Vicky Khichar's answer, the options are being populated correctly.

Also, in testing last night, I found that using `$(document).ready` doesn't make any difference.

This appears to be 100% a DOM issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more testing, I found that even though JQuery displays the row and everything else, it also sets:

```
style="width:0"
```

After hours of trying to figure out what's going wrong, I finally figured out that a simple command was all I was missing, which I would have thought JQuery wouldn't have required.

```
$("#dropdownId").css("width", "200px");
```

Once it has a valid width, it works as intended. Why this has to be a manual thing, IDK. This seems like a hack. I don't like it, but it works, so it's what I'm using.

After setting that correctly, I can use the first drop down list to hide and show the target one without any issues.  It evidently has to be only after the drop down list is visible. Trying to do it while it's hidden doesn't work.

In the original code, I do have the drop down list width set to 200px. Why that doesn't carry over, IDK. Why that's changed at all, I also don't know.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.NotChosenReason, Model.NotChosenReasons,
    new { @class = "chosen-select-deselect", data_placeholder = "Select Not Chosen Reason", style = "width:200px;" })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@section scripts {
<script>
    //For hide html table on page load
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ifNotChosen').hide();

    //here you can bind the value in dropdown list.

    });


    //For Show table on dropdown change
    $("#dropdownId").change(function(){
        $('#ifNotChosen').show();
    }); 
</script>
}
```

You have to bind data in dropdown list when your page gets load, So after this when you select from the table you will find the value inside it.

Comment: I did some testing late last night and forgot to update my question, unfortunately. I'm sorry about that as it affects your answer. I found that using $(document).ready doesn't make any difference, unfortunately. This morning in testing your idea about populating the DDL from the script, I found that the options are actually being added, they just don't show up. I didn't realize that until just now. This is apparently 100% a DOM issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are loading jQuery *after* that script in the resulting HTML.  Typically, in razor views you would place your scripts in a special named section that get renders by your `_Layout` *after* loading jQuery.

So in your page:

```
@section scripts {
 <script>...</script>
}
```

and in your _Layout.cshtml, somewhere near the bottom:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

This way, your scripts in your page get executed *after* jQuery gets loaded

Comment: The JQuery gets included at the top of the page and the other JQuery on the page works just fine.  I'll add that to the question so others don't make this same mistake.  Also, this is a new field to a working form.